# Show an integral inequality $\int_{0}^{\phi}f\left(x^{\phi}\right)+f\left(\phi^{\phi}-x\right)dx<\phi$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, definite-integrals, golden-ratio

Denote by $\phi$ the golden ratio then show the inequality :

$$\int_{0}^{\phi}f\left(x^{\phi}\right)+f\left(\phi^{\phi}-x\right)dx<\phi$$

Where :

$$f\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

---

---

My attempt :

Using the concavity of $f(x)$ on the domain of the integral we have :

$$f(x)\leq f'\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)+f\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$$

Which is currently not sufficient . We can use two derivative instead but by hand it becomes tedious .

---

---

Second attempt :

Using logarithm and derivative on the domain of the integral we have :

$$g(x)=\left(\frac{x+1}{x+7}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{1-\sqrt{1+\left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)}}{\frac{16}{16\ln\left(2\right)-11}}\geq f(x)$$

Using a computer we have :

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(f\left(x^{a}\right)+f\left(a^{a}-x\right)\right)dx+\int_{1}^{a}\left(g\left(x^{a}\right)+g\left(a^{a}-x\right)\right)dx<\phi=a$$

Then we have this [monster](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Integral%22%2C%20%22integrand%22%7D%20-%3E%22%28%28x%5E%281%2F2%2B%285%2F4%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29%2B1%29%2F%28x%5E%281%2F2%2B%285%2F4%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29%2B7%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22integral%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D)

---

---

Last attempt :

Again on the domain of the integral we have :

$$h(x)=\frac{4}{5}\left(\frac{x+1}{x+4}\right)-\frac{1}{5}+e^{-1}+\frac{7\sqrt{x}}{94\cdot2e}-\frac{x^{2}\left(x-1\right)}{256}\geq \left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

Then with a computer we have :

$$\int_{0}^{\phi}\left(h\left(x^{\phi}\right)+f\left(\phi^{\phi}-x\right)\right)dx<\phi$$

---

---

Can we pretend to show it by hand without the use of a computer ? If too hard can we show it analytically with the help of a computer for computing  some constant ?

Comment: A similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2111571/305862)

Comment: Using mental calculation (!!) $rhs-lhs \sim  0.0010$ (joke)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the answer is : hopefuly not by hand because this inequality is very **tight** as you can see on this figure, where we have plotted the curve of $f$ (in green) and the curve of  the integrand function (blue curve):

$$y=g(x)=f(x^{\varphi})+f(\varphi^{\varphi}-x)$$

The mean value $m$ of $g$ looks to be very close to $1$ on interval $(0, \varphi)$, giving an integral very close to $m \times \text{interval length}$; i.e., close very close to $1(\varphi - 0)=\varphi$.

[image]

Comment: Edit I make a mistake .

Comment: (+1) for the interesting comment ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell the origin of this problem ?

Comment: It comes  directly from my imagination and some luck !